# What is the size of ValueType when declared as part of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

In case of this class

```
public class Foo {public Int32 MyField; }
```

What will be the size of MyField? Is it only 4bytes on x86 machine, or it has usual overhead for objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyField` will be 4 bytes, the overhead is for the parent `Foo` object.